# "No common protection layer between client and server" while trying to communicate with kerberized Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, cloudera-cdh

I'm trying to communicate programmatically to a Hadoop cluster which is kerberized (CDH 5.3/HDFS 2.5.0).

I have a valid Kerberos token on the client side.  But I'm getting an error as below, "No common protection layer between client and server".

What does this error mean and are there any ways to fix or work around it?

Is this something related to [HDFS-5688](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-5688)? The ticket seems to imply that the property "hadoop.rpc.protection" must be set, presumably to "authentication" (also per e.g. [this](https://datameer.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204262060-Errors-when-Executing-Job-Caused-by-javax-security-sasl-SaslException-No-common-protection-layer-between-client-and-server)).

Would this need to be set on all servers in the cluster and then the cluster bounced?  I don't have easy access to the cluster so I need to understand whether 'hadoop.rpc.protection' is the actual cause. It seems that 'authentication' should be the value used by default, at least according to the core-default.xml documentation.

java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't setup connection for principal1/server1.acme.net@xxx.acme.net to server2.acme.net/10.XX.XXX.XXX:8020; Host Details : local host is: “some-host.acme.net/168.XX.XXX.XX”; destination host is: “server2.acme.net”:8020;

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:764)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1415)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)

    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:707)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1785)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1068)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)

    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)

    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1398)

    ... 11 more
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't setup connection for principal1/server1.acme.net@xxx.acme.net to server2.acme.net/10.XX.XXX.XXX:8020;

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:671)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:642)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:725)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:367)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1463)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1382)

    ... 31 more
```

Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: No common protection layer between client and server

```
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.doFinalHandshake(GssKrb5Client.java:251)

    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:186)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslEvaluateToken(SaslRpcClient.java:483)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:427)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:552)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1800(Client.java:367)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:717)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:713)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)

    ... 34 more
```

Comment: From the famous GitBook **Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate**: *"No common protection layer between client and server >> Not Kerberos, SASL itself"* https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/errors.html

Answer (score 8):

To fix the "No common protection between client and server" error which is coming from SASL, I needed to set "hadoop.rpc.protection" to the same value as the one set on the serverside in the cluster. It happened to be "privacy" in this case.

Additionally, the cluster is configured for HA so I had to pick the right hostname to use in the HDFS URI ("fs.defaultFS") and in the "dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal" property:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://host1.acme.com:8020");
config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
config.set("hadoop.rpc.protection", "privacy");
// Need this or we get the error "Server has invalid Kerberos principal":
config.set("dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal",  
    "hdfs/host1.acme.com@ACME.DYN.ROOT.NET");
```

Comment: The easy way to handle these config issues is to *(a)* copy the whole set of `*-site.xml` files from one of the cluster nodes *(b)* drop them in a local directory *(c)* add that directory in your CLASSPATH -- the `Configuration` constructor (and its derivatives for Hive, HBase etc.) uses the same logic as Log4J i.e. search the CLASSPATH for directories, and search for predefined file names in these directories. If no files are found then `Configuration` reverts to hard-coded "default" values, without any warning.

Comment: Samson, yes absolutely. That would be the easy route but our application is multi-purpose and will be interfacing with 5-6 different clusters. That means we'd need to maintain 5-6 .properties files of our own plus at least 5-6 x 2 XML files (core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml). On top of that, the host names used in the XML files are cluster-internal and won't resolve if we're running outside the cluster. We're also not in control of any changes on the cluster side, so the files may get stale on our side.

Comment: Duh... anyway you won't reasonably use *hard-coded* properties, so you will have to maintain 5-6 (custom) properties files. One way or another.

Comment: it depends who manages hadoop cluster, if they r under control of Cloudera or Ambari - it would be more easy to use their API to get actual configuration of services. If it is raw cluster....you could propose to user fill those configuration himself.

Comment: We ended up implementing a job which automatically copies the Hadoop XML files down to a dedicated location on the ETL servers for us. We just load those using the HDFS API when connecting, pretty much as Samson is describing. The job automatically sends out email notifications to the interested parties so we're always aware of the configuration changes made by the cluster devops team...